# Windows/Python pygame.error: video system not initialized after adding Mp3 file

Tags: python, pygame

I just added some music to my pygame game but I think the code is so messy that nothing is in the right place. As a result of this addition, I'm now getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\1234\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\My First game
>   ERROR.py", line 31, in 
>       for event in pygame.event.get(): pygame.error: video system not initialized

Here is the code that I have written:

```
import pygame, sys

pygame.mixer.init(44100, -16,2,2048)

class Game(object):
def main(self, screen):

    import time
pygame.mixer.music.load('The Tonight Show Star Wars The Bee Gees Stayin     Alive Shortened.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)

#class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
   # def __init__(self, *groups):
   # super(Player, self.__init__(*groups)
    #self.image = pygame.image.load('Sprite-01.png')
   # self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((320, 240), self.image.get_size())

    #def update(self):
       # key = pygame

image = pygame.image.load('Sprite-01.png')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
# initialize variables
image_x = 0
image_y = 0

while 1:
clock.tick(30)     
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.quit():
        pygame.quit()
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
        pygame.quit()

image_x += 0
key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    image_x -= 10
if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    image_x += 10
if key[pygame.K_UP]:
    image_y -= 10
if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
    image_y += 10

screen.fill((200, 200, 200))
screen.blit(image, (image_x, image_y))
pygame.display.flip()

pygame.mixer.music.stop(52)


if __name__ == '__main__':
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
pygame.display.set_caption('St.Patrick game')
Game().main(screen)
```

Comment: Please indent your code correctly, so that we can see exactly what you see in your editor. Click edit, paste your code, select it all and press Ctrl+K or the `{}` button to format it correctly.

Comment: Sorry I was just manually adding in four spaces.

Comment: Just post your code on https://pastebin.com/ or https://gist.github.com/ for the moment so that we can see how your program actually looks like (we can add it to the post for you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the problem. You're checking `if event.type == pygame.quit():` in the event loop whereas you should check `if event.type == pygame.QUIT:`. That means the first time the event loop is executed, you call `pygame.quit()` in this line and uninitialize all modules whereupon you cannot use many pygame functions anymore and the `pygame.error` is raised.

I think you actually want your program to look more like this version:

```
import pygame


pygame.mixer.init(44100, -16,2,2048)


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, *groups):
        super(Player, self.__init__(*groups))
        self.image = pygame.image.load('Sprite-01.png')
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((320, 240), self.image.get_size())


class Game(object):

    def main(self, screen):
        # pygame.mixer.music.load('The Tonight Show Star Wars The Bee Gees Stayin     Alive Shortened.mp3')
        # pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)

        # image = pygame.image.load('Sprite-01.png')
        image = pygame.Surface((30, 50))
        image.fill((0, 90, 240))

        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        # initialize variables
        image_x = 0
        image_y = 0

        done = False
        while not done:
            clock.tick(30)
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    done = True
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    done = True

            key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                image_x -= 10
            if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                image_x += 10
            if key[pygame.K_UP]:
                image_y -= 10
            if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                image_y += 10

            screen.fill((200, 200, 200))
            screen.blit(image, (image_x, image_y))
            pygame.display.flip()

            # pygame.mixer.music.stop(52)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    pygame.display.set_caption('St.Patrick game')
    Game().main(screen)
    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: It actually makes no sense to use a `Game` class here, since it only contains one method. You could just turn the `main` method into a normal function.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the issue is that you did not initialize the `pygame` module.

**All pygame scripts must call the `init` function before using anything from the pygame library.**

In your code, you have the line `pygame.init()` included. However, the line is in the wrong place and there is code that uses the pygame library before this line.

Luckily this problem is very easy to fix.

**To fix this problem:**

- Add the line `pygame.init()` at the start of your script.

I hope this answer helped you and if you have any further queries please feel free to post a comment below!

Comment: Where exactly does it need to be added?

Comment: I tried to add it in but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Just after you import pygame.

Comment: # This just imports all the Pygame modules
import pygame
pygame.init()

class Game(object):
    def main(self, screen):

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48286251/windows-python-pygame-error-video-system-not-initialized-after-adding-mp3-file

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1234\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\My First game ERROR.py", line 18, in <module>
    for event in pygame.event.get():
pygame.error: video system not initialized

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163283/discussion-between-micheal-odwyer-and-isaac-volpe).